# linux bash, passing paramenters using a varible issue

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use a variable  to store the parameters, here is the simple test:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed_args="-e \"s/aaaa/bbbb/g\""
echo $sed_args`
```

I expected the output to be

```
-e "s/aaaa/bbbb/g"
```

but it gives:

```
"s/aaaa/bbbb/g"
```

without the  "-e"

I am new to bash, any comment is welcome. Thanks, maybe this is already answered somewhere.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the variable without double quotes, it gets word split by the shell even before `echo` sees the value(s). Then, the bash's builtin `echo` interprets `-e` as a parameter for itself (which is normally used to turn on interpretation of backslash escapes).

When you double quote the variable, it won't be split and will be interpreted as a single argument to echo:

```
echo "$sed_args"
```

For strings you don't control, it's safer to use `printf` as it doesn't take any arguments after the format string:

```
printf %s "$string"
```

Comment: Another question relates to this is if you feed the sed_args to sed, another error just shows up: sed: -e expression #1, char: unknown command `"'. if I simply copy the output of $sed_args, and type the sed command by hand with the argument, things work nicely.  However, in the script it pops that error.

Comment: @ChundeHuang: That's because when you type the double quotes directly at the command line, they're removed in quote removal. When they're part of a string, the removal happens before the string gets interpreted, so they remain part of the arguments.

Comment: I just realized that, thanks very much for your time and help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need an array to construct arguments dynamically:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed_args=('-e' 's/aaaa/bbbb/g')
echo "${sed_args[@]}"
```

Comment: For the OP's limited use case, this is not strictly necessary; but there are many situations where arrays are absolutely the only way to do this correctly.

Comment: This doesn't output the `-e`.

Comment: @choroba the `-e` is not printed by echo because it is captured as argument to `echo`. If you want to echo the argument you'd have to `echo "${sed_args[*]}"` but then this would be unwanted to expand the array entries as individual arguments for `sed`.